# Help With Complex Plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello everyone I have a number w that equals to:

w = $-0.5 + 0.5 \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot i$

And I have to proof that:

$(w-1)^{n} + (\bar{w}-1)^{n} \in$$ \{{0 , \pm  \sqrt{3^n} , \pm \sqrt{3^{n+1}} , \pm 2 \sqrt{3^n} }\}$

Comment: Change both $w-1$ and its conjugate into trigonometric form.

Comment: Can you show that please?

Comment: I will. Just a moment

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$
w - 1 =  - \frac{3}
{2} + \frac{{i\sqrt 3 }}
{2}
$$
thus
$
r = \left| {w - 1} \right| = \sqrt {a^2  + b^2 }  = \sqrt 3 
$
and
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \cos \theta  = \frac{a}
{r} =  - \frac{3}
{{2\sqrt 3 }} =  - \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}
{2} \hfill \\
  \sin \theta  = \frac{b}
{r} = \frac{1}
{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
therefore $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{6}$
Hence
$$
w - 1 = \left( {\sqrt 3 } \right)\left( {\cos \frac{{5\pi }}
{6} + i\sin \frac{{5\pi }}
{6}} \right)
$$
and from De Moivre's Theorem you have
$$
\left( {w - 1} \right)^n = \left( {\sqrt 3 } \right)^n \left( {\cos \frac{{5\pi n}}
{6} + i\sin \frac{{5\pi n}}
{6}} \right)
.$$
In the same way
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \overline w  - 1 =  - \frac{3}
{2} - i\frac{{\sqrt 3 }}
{2} \hfill \\
  r = \sqrt 3  \hfill \\
  \cos \theta  =  - \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}
{2} \hfill \\
  \sin \theta  =  - \frac{1}
{2} \hfill \\
  \theta  = \frac{{7\pi }}
{6} =  - \frac{{5\pi }}
{6} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
thus
$$
\left( {\overline w  - 1} \right)^n  = \left( {\sqrt 3 } \right)^n \left( {\cos \frac{{5\pi n}}
{6} - i\sin \frac{{5\pi n}}
{6}} \right)
$$
Now
$$
\left( {w - 1} \right)^n  + \left( {\overline w  - 1} \right)^n  = 2\left( {\sqrt 3 } \right)^n \left( {\cos \frac{{5\pi n}}
{6}} \right)
$$
Now, the sequence
$$
a_n  = \cos \left( {\frac{{5\pi n}}
{6}} \right)
$$
is periodic with period $12$. Its values are

1. $a_1=-\sqrt{3}/2$
2. $a_2=1/2$
3. $a_3=0$
4. $a_4=-1/2$
5. $a_5=\sqrt{3}/2$
6. $a_6=-1$
7. $a_7=\sqrt{3}/2$
8. $a_8=-1/2$
9. $a_9=0$
10. $a_{10}=1/2$
11. $a_{11}=-\sqrt{3}/2$
12. $a_{12}=1$.

After that, the values are repeating with period $12$. If you combine this values with the factor $2(\sqrt{3})^n$ you get the result.

Comment: This is equal to $ 2\cdot \sqrt{3^n} \cdot$ cos(150n) right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. You are welcome.

Comment: Can you reduce it more?

Comment: Yes, just a moment